# Yarn is installed but does not work. Command is recognized but no yarn commands do anything. Windows Powershell

Tags: powershell, npm-install, yarnpkg

node version 11.13.0
npm version 6.9.0
I have installed yarn multiple ways, first with the `npm install -g yarn`, then I tried the .msi installer, and I also tried installing with chocolatey from an elevated shell. Usually, when I try to use something I have not installed, I get a message that looks like this:

```
  PS C:\Users\[me]> hello
hello : The term 'hello' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ hello
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (hello:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

However, `yarn` commands are recognized but do nothing.

```
PS C:\Users\[me]> yarn --version
PS C:\Users\[me]>
```

I've tried changing the Path environment variable to include the following:

```
C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn
C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin
```

but this didn't change anything.

Comment: What does `Get-Command yarn` give you as an output? Does it point to correct file?

Comment: @robdy It yields a `yarn.cmd` file in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\yarn.cmd`. I think this might be the problem! How do I change that to the correct directory?

Comment: I'd remove Nodist folder from `$PATH`, but I don't know about the exact configuration you have and what you want to achieve :)

Comment: Looks like it didn't work out. I tried uninstalling nodist but it turns out that's where node and npm were also being run from. I installed all three without nodist but now npm does nothing even though the command is recognized, and yarn still does nothing.

Answer (score 14):

you must be add %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm in environment path

1-search environment in the start menu
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4zxD.jpg

2-Click environment variables
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B59yD.jpg

3-edit path of user variables
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz73p.jpg

4-add URI of yarn as new
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rq7xK.jpg

then after that if can't use yarn command in vscode and get error yarn.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system;  open Powershell as Administrator and run below command

Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

Answer (score 1):

`--version` is not a valid switch, use `yarn version` instead - https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/version.

Comment: `yarn version` doesn't do anything either. None of the yarn commands work.

Answer (score 0):

Even after adding environment variable on windows I got error. Here is fix
`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm` in environment path

Open windows command shell as administrator and run command:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are not comfortable with changing Execution policy, here's a solution that worked for me:

Solution: the problem was one extra "\" was missing after bin.

Before: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm`

After: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\`

Answer (score 0):

Below solution worked for me,
set the PATH environment variable as below

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\bin
```