# Error in VS Code during setting up client for project

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-line-interface, create-react-app

The term 'yarn' is not recognized as the
name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

```
+ yarn create vite client
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (yar  
   n:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundExcep  
   tion
  ~~~~
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43313178/react-native-error-yarn-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Answer (score 1):

Refer To This link for solution

[You need to set the Path environment variable after installing yarn in order to execute the yarn command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68963336/23112610)

You can either enter the path given in the link or use path "C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Roaming\npm" where u need to edit the "<user-name>" as per your user.